# assigning values to variables and iterate over columns using enumerate from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe,

```
    a   b   c
0   1   7   1
1   10  9   2
2   8   3   3
3   11  6   4
```

My idea is to use a loop, such as:

```
for ind, column in enumerate(df):
    dummy_ + str(ind) = df[column].nlargest()
```

in order to get the following variables:

```
dummy_1 = 11
dummy_2 = 9
dummy_3 = 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a great idea to "dynamically create" variables within a loop as you're trying to do here.  Would you consider using a dictionary where your keys are string forms of `dummy_n`?  This is really what dictionaries are made for and it can be easier to work with a single data structure that encapsulates all of your dummy variables and their values.

Comment: You are simply getting the rowwise max. You can get a dictionary like this: df.max().add_prefix('dummy_').to_dict()

Comment: Thanks Vaishali! Although the solution you propose is getting the max considering only the first column.

Comment: Thanks for answering Brad Solomon! That's a good idea!

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean but the solution I proposed gives {'dummy_a': 11, 'dummy_b': 9, 'dummy_c': 4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as you saw.

```
pd.Series(index=['dummy_'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,4))],data=df.max(0).values)
Out[706]: 
dummy_1    11
dummy_2     9
dummy_3     4
dtype: int64
```

Or

```
['dummy_'+str(i)+'='+str(j) for i,j in zip(list(range(1,4)),df.max(0).values)]
Out[708]: ['dummy_1=11', 'dummy_2=9', 'dummy_3=4']
```

Answer (score 2):

Well Its not a great idea though But in case you want it,learn the use of exec function which will execute the string written as arguments

```
for ind, column in enumerate(df):
    exec("dummy_ +"+str(ind)+"= df[column].nlargest()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted variable names unrelated to original column names; you can specify them first in a list, rename the columns, then create a series from the max values:

```
var_names = ['dummy_'+str(el) for el in range(1,4)]
(df.rename(columns=lambda _,y=iter(var_names):next(y))
 .max()
)
Out:
dummy_1    11
dummy_2     9
dummy_3     4
dtype: int64
```

This is essentially a variation of Vaishali's original comment:

```
df.max().add_prefix('dummy_')
Out:
dummy_a    11
dummy_b     9
dummy_c     4
dtype: int64
```